# Storing dictionary variables in list after test

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json structured like this:

```
{   "status":"OK", "copyright":"Copyright (c) 2017 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.","results":[
  {
     "member_id": "B001288",
     "total_votes": "100",
     "offset": "0",
     "votes": [
       {
       "member_id": "B001288",
       "chamber": "Senate",
       "congress": "115",
       "session": "1",
       "roll_call": "84",
       "bill": {
         "number": "H.J.Res.57",
         "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/bills/hjres57.json",
         "title": "Providing for congressional disapproval under chapter 8 of title 5, United States Code, of the rule submitted by the Department of Education relating to accountability and State plans under the Elementary and Secondary Education Act of 1965.",
         "latest_action": "Message on Senate action sent to the House."
       },
       "description": "A joint resolution providing for congressional disapproval under chapter 8 of title 5, United States Code, of the rule submitted by the Department of Education relating to accountability and State ...",
       "question": "On the Joint Resolution",
       "date": "2017-03-09",
       "time": "12:02:00",
       "position": "No"
     },
```

Sometimes the "bill" parameter is there, sometimes it is blank, like:

```
{
       "member_id": "B001288",
       "chamber": "Senate",
       "congress": "115",
       "session": "1",
       "roll_call": "79",
       "bill": {
       },
       "description": "James Richard Perry, of Texas, to be Secretary of Energy",
       "question": "On the Nomination",
       "date": "2017-03-02",
       "time": "13:46:00",
       "position": "No"
     },
```

I want to access and store the "bill_uri" in a list, so I can access it later on. I've already performed `.json()` through the requests package to process it into python. `print votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][0]["bill"]["bill_uri"]` etc. works just fine, but when I do:

```
bill_urls_2 = []
for n in range(0, len(votes_json["results"][0]["votes"])):
    if votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"]["bill_uri"] in votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]:
        bill_urls_2.append(votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n])["bill"]["bill_uri"]

print bill_urls_2
```

I get the error `KeyError: 'bill_uri'`. I think I have a problem with the structure of the if statement, specifically what key I'm looking for in the dictionary. Could someone provide an explanation/link to explanation about how to use `in` to find keys? Or pinpoint the error in how I'm using it?

Update: Aha! I got this to work:

```
bill_urls_2 = []

for n in range(0, len(votes_json["results"][0]["votes"])):
    if "bill" in votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]:
        if "bill_uri" in votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"]:
            bill_urls_2.append(votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"]["bill_uri"])

print bill_urls_2
```

Thank you to everyone who gave me advice.

Comment: You have not provided enough of the JSON to validate this. Note that `votes` is a list, and we don't see more than one element in that list. It's possible that `votes[1]` does not contain `['bill'][bill_uri']`.

Comment: with the `json` sample you've provided: `for n in votes_json["results"][0]["votes"]:
    bill_urls_2.append(n['bill']['bill_uri'])` should work. I'm sure it could be easily modified to work with the entire `json` object

Comment: I should have clarified. Sometimes the json has the "bill' parameter, sometimes it does not, so I'm pretty sure I need the if statement. I've edited my original post.

Comment: Aha, ok. `if votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"]["bill_uri"] in votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]:` first looks for `votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"]["bill_uri"]`. So it will automatically fail if `bill_uri` doesn't exist. Use `if votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"].get(["bill_uri"]):` and remove the remainder of the `if` statement. Does that work?

Comment: In other words, your current `if` check first requires the key to exist before you check whether it exists (and in the case that it does, you take the _value_ and look for that as a _key_), all in one line. I'm not entirely confident I understand what you're doing before I write an answer though, so please try that suggestion and report back.

Comment: The edit almost confirms it. Does `if votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"].get("bill_uri"‌​):` work as your replacement `if` statement? EDIT: I incorrectly had "bill_uri" inside a list e.g. `.get(["bill_uri"‌​])` in my first comment. I have fixed it in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is cause by the fact that you are looking for a key in the dictionary by called that key itself. Here's a small example:

```
my_dict = {'A': 1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
```

Now *C* may or may not exist in the dict every time. This is how I can check if *C* exists in the dict:

```
if 'C' in my_dict:
    print(True)
```

What you are doing is:

```
if my_dict['C'] in my_dict:
    print(True)
```

If *C* doesn't exist to begin with `my_dict['C']` isn't found and gives you an error.

What you need to do is:

```
bill_urls_2 = []
for n in range(0, len(votes_json["results"][0]["votes"])):
    if "bill_uri" in votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]:
        bill_urls_2.append(votes_json["results"][0]["votes"][n]["bill"]["bill_uri"])

print bill_urls_2
```

Comment: The `KeyError` is on `bill_uri` so it appears that it's not enough that it contains a `bill` key.

Comment: I put your code in and got the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` Edit: Nevermind, I had a syntax error. Now I'm getting the same `KeyError` as before.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is just an example. You will have to check for both ``bill`` and ``bill_uri``. This is assuming ``bill`` isn't always present. If it is then just check for ``bill_uri``

Comment: @wirefire can you tell me where you made the change? Maybe update the question with what you tried